# KeyboardAvoidingView adds space by itself

Tags: react-native, keyboard

when I click on the input box within the KeyboardAvoidingView with behaviour="position" the view gets pushed to the top leaving too much margin in bottom and once I type anything in the input box it goes back to the keyboardVerticalOffset position[image]

[image]

Comment: try using height for android. `<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}>{/*your components*/}</KeyboardAvoidingView>` Remember to `import` `Platform` from `react-native`

Comment: If I use height then again some padding bottom is added which then cannot be changed even with keyboardVerticalOffset. I tried with padding too that wont even reflect any changes .Thanks